# lxml incorrectly parsing the Doctype while looking for links

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, lxml

I've got a BeautifulSoup4 (4.2.1) parser which collects all `href` attributes from our template files, and until now it has been just perfect. But with lxml installed, one of our guys is now getting a;

`TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

I managed to replicate this on my Linux Mint VM and the only difference appears to be lxml so I assume when bs4 uses that html parser the issue occurs.

The problem function is;

```
def collecttemplateurls(templatedir, urlslist):
    """
    Uses BeautifulSoup to extract all the external URLs from the templates dir.

    @return: list of URLs
    """
    for (dirpath, dirs, files) in os.walk(templatedir):
        for path in (Path(dirpath, f) for f in files):
            if path.endswith(".html"):
                for link in BeautifulSoup(
                        open(path).read(),
                        parse_only=SoupStrainer(target="_blank")
                ):
                    if link["href"].startswith('http://'):
                        urlslist.append(link['href'])

                    elif link["href"].startswith('{{'):
                        for l in re.findall("'(http://(?:.*?))'", link["href"]):
                            urlslist.append(l)

    return urlslist
```

So for this one guy, the line `if link["href"].startswith('http://'):` gives the Type error because BS4 thinks the html Doctype is a link.

Can anyone explain what the problem here might be because nobody else can recreate it?

I can't see how this could happen when using SoupStrainer like this. I assume it's somehow related to a system setup issue.

I can't see anything particularly special about our Doctype;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-gb">

<head>
```

Comment: I couldn't replicate your issue. I used BeautifulSoup version 3.2.0 and `BeautifulSoup(html,parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer(target="_blank"))`

Comment: @Sudipta As soon as I installed lxml (3.2.3) on my Windows machine it started to happen. I'm not sure what html parser bs4 was using before, but I have to assume the issue comes from lxml now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SoupStrainer` will not filter out the document type; it filters what elements remain in document, but the doc-type is retained as it is part of the 'container' for the filtered elements. You are looping over **all** elements in the document, so the first element you encounter is the `DocType` object.

Use `.find_all()` on the 'strained' document:

```
document = BeautifulSoup(open(path).read(), parse_only=SoupStrainer(target="_blank"))
for link in documen.find_all(target="_blank"):
```

or filter out the `DocType` object:

```
from bs4 import DocType

for link in BeautifulSoup(
        open(path).read(),
        parse_only=SoupStrainer(target="_blank")
):
    if isinstance(link, Doctype): continue
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! I've gone with the `find_all` method as I never use `: continue` (not sure how that works with principles & best practise!)

Comment: `continue` is a perfectly fine statement; it is right up there with `return` and `break`. :-)